# How to make a fortress that can withstand Elemental benders

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, warfare

My world has elemental magic users similar to Avatar: The Last Air Bender.

With this in mind how would fortresses and castles be designed so that they could withstand an army when almost every army will have several elemental benders in them.

- High middle ages technology level
- There is about 1 bender to every 15 to 20 normal people (I can't say how many would be in the army because the builders of the fortresses don't know what armies they will face in the future)

For reference: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender

Comment: Is it the same 4 classic elements? Air, water, earth, fire? If so, can you have a newly discovered 5th element? It might be something like lightening. Something that isn't affected by the other 4, maybe with a new bender to shape it. Other wise some kind of area effect that nullifies benders.

Comment: Define "element" and "army" and "bender" or else I fear people will make assumptions and answers will vary completely.

Comment: @Zxyrra those terms are well-defined by the phrase "similar to Avatar". I edited the question to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: @SRM People will still need specifics - how much can someone bend, for how often; how hot can the fire get, how fast can they do it; how big is the army - while your story doesn't need these details it will affect how the attack works, and thus how the defense does

Comment: Irrelevant to the question. The question asks for a general technology vector, not a tactical defense plan.

Comment: @SRM  by saying "there are benders" it's impossible to know how to stop them - if there are 10, you will need a fortress built differently than if there were 1000, for instance.

Comment: This has been nominated for re-open. It is a good question but it is still asked poorly. I wish this question would get some cleanup and get reposted.

Comment: @SRM people build castles towers and fortresses without knowing what enemies they will face what seeds equipment they will have or how many toops they will send against them, yet they seem to do a pretty good job defending themselves some historical perspective by just knowing the gist of what they can expect why should this be any different

Comment: @BryanMcClure You and I are in agreement.

Answer (score 2):

## Build Out Of Living Trees

If you can grow trees into custom shapes, you get a structure that cannot be directly touched by any of the benders. Water might come close (sap bending similar to blood bending), but sufficiently rigid hardwood would require immense strength to flex and living greenwood would just bend, not break (no pun intended).

The giant hardwood trees survive regular attacks by fire quite well.

The scale and flexibility make large trees, particularly ones with mutual support, able to survive tornadoes and hurricanes. There is a threshold beyond which no structure is ok -- just lifting it out of the ground even if no other damage. But that's a pretty big storm.

Rocks thrown at the trees are a concern, as are cutting blades (airbender with a spinning metal disk), but there are hardwoods like iron wood that are bloody hard to get through even with modern power tools.

Make sure you get a dense weave of branches as your floors to avoid stuff coming up from the ground.

That's about the best defense I can offer. Only problem is that such a structure has to be grown over time. Not fast to build.

Answer (score 1):

## Psychology Defense

Consider spreading rumors about your fortress located on the vast plains of western Oklahoma -- or your favorite patch of empty, flat land -- a fortress fully capable of defending *itself*, crafted from raw qi itself.

The enemy army rides into view. They see no fortress. They can see 17 miles clean across the prairie/desert/whatever. As they draw closer, they see you and your troops seated calmly in open air. Project an air of confidence. Have one messenger ride out to meet the invaders. The messenger says, "Come no closer. You are in danger. The fortress will destroy you if it believes you come as a threat."

Let the enemy psych itself out trying to tear down your non-existent walls. Because when warriors fight wielding the basic building blocks of the world, your best bet is to take away their tools.

Answer (score 0):

The 5th element could have a nullifying effect as mentioned in other comments, thus the wielder of that element could imbue or surround the fortress effectively nullifying all elemental powers that come in contact with the fifth element.